# How to create Asp.net c# Custom control with properties select from a dropdownlist?

Tags: custom-controls, typeconverter

How to create Asp.net c# Custom control with properties select from a dropdownlist?

Example: I try to create my own TextBox inherit from TextBox.
It has a property named "MyOwnColor". When add custom control to Visual Studio, in the properties window, property "MyOwnColor" can input by type Text to input field.
So, what can i replace input field with a dropdownlist that has some selection are set by me?

Image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UaLV.jpg
I want to create properties like Border Style.
I have read some sucguest about "TypeConverter" but i don't know how to use ...

Can you help me?

I am bad at English. 
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I've asked on some forum and answer is: Use an enum.

```
public enum Color
        {
            Red,
            Blue,
            Green
        }
```